# Gas furnace vent clearance from parallel PVC radon vent

Tags: exhaust-vent, fire-hazard

I have a hallow wall on my main floor which carries my gas furnace vent up thru the attic and out the roof. This picture is from the basement looking up at the vent and as you can see, the radon mitigation company installed the radon 4 inch PVC right up against the galvanized steel gas vent. Do I need to have them move this over? What should the clearance be / ie what is code?

[image]

From what I can find, code for type B gas furnace vent is "1 inch away from combustible material." Maybe the question is: PVC Considered combustible material?